# Missing apt-get package for pine64

Tags: debian, apt

I've got a pine64 board, which is running the arm64 version of debian.  I'd like to build lgogdownloader, which suggests I should use this apt-get command:

```
apt install build-essential libcurl4-openssl-dev libboost-regex-dev \
libjsoncpp-dev liboauth-dev librhash-dev libtinyxml2-dev libhtmlcxx-dev\
libboost-system-dev libboost-filesystem-dev libboost-program-options-dev\
libboost-date-time-dev help2man cmake libssl-dev
```

But this gives me a missing package error:

```
E: Unable to locate package libhtmlcxx-devlibboost-system-dev
E: Unable to locate package libboost-program-options-devlibboost-date-time-dev
```

How do I go about fixing this? I presume this is just that no-ones built those packages for the arm64 architecture?  Could I do it myself? How?

Comment: The first step would be to download the sources `apt-get source pkgname`. See if you can download those. But a more productive approach might be to email the Debian mailing list for your arch and ask for help and advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've dropped some spaces: it's `libhtmlcxx-dev libboost-system-dev` and `libboost-program-options-dev libboost-date-time-dev`. You need to add a space before two of the `\`s in your command:

```
apt install build-essential libcurl4-openssl-dev libboost-regex-dev \
libjsoncpp-dev liboauth-dev librhash-dev libtinyxml2-dev libhtmlcxx-dev \
libboost-system-dev libboost-filesystem-dev libboost-program-options-dev \
libboost-date-time-dev help2man cmake libssl-dev
```

But [`lgogdownloader`](https://tracker.debian.org/lgogdownloader) is already available for `arm64`, in Debian 8 (stable), testing and unstable; so you should just be able to install that directly.

```
apt install lgogdownloader
```

If you do want to rebuild it, a simpler option to install the build dependencies is to run

```
sudo apt-get build-dep lgogdownloader
```

I've uploaded version 2.28 to Jessie backports, so that could be an option too if you're running Debian 8 and would like a newer version of `lgogdownloader` (once it's accepted into the archive). (I'm the `lgogdownloader` maintainer in Debian.)

Comment: Thanks - that looks better!  The version of lgogdownloader I'm getting through apt didn't seem able to communicate with gog properly, so I thought I'd try building it myself.

Comment: Also, the instructions on https://github.com/Sude-/lgogdownloader appear to be wrong, if you can get them updated!

Comment: Ah right, I didn't realise the Jessie version couldn't communicate with gog.com properly... I uploaded 2.28 to Jessie backports yesterday, it's in the queue and should be available soon (and I'll make sure newer versions are uploaded too). I'll submit a patch to update the instructions on Sude's site!

Comment: https://github.com/Sude-/lgogdownloader/pull/84